# Inserting into a tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

In a Java file, I have the following code:

```
MyTree atree = new MyTree();
atree.insert(1);
```

This is not a regular tree. "atree" is the root node. Every node in this tree has 5 children, all initially set to null. The parameter for insert is the child that you want to 'activate', that is, make it non-null. So I have a method in the MyTree class that does this:

```
public void insert(int i)
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
        MyTree current = this.getChildOne();
        current = new MyTree();
    }
}
```

After I call the function, I check the first node in the file where I called it.

```
if(atree.getChildOne() == null)
{
    return -1;
}
```

And it always returns negative one. I suspect that the insert function is actually working on a copy of 'atree' and not the actual 'atree'. But I am not entirely sure. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: You provide only bits and pieces of code. That isn't enough. This isn't a binary tree, right ?

Comment: No. Each node has five children instead of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are assigning child one anywhere. The code

```
MyTree current = this.getChildOne();
current = new MyTree();
```

does not assign child one. You initialize a local variable `current` but then that variable is lost when the method ends.

I think you probably want to do something like this in your insert method

```
if ( i == i ) {
   this.childOne = // assign it here
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error that says "The left operand must be a variable".

Comment: Yes, you would need a variable named childOne in your tree for this to work. You need to provide some way to set the variable. You also need to replace the code on the right side of the equals method with the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

The line `current = new MyTree()` changes the local variable `current`: it had pointed to the instance that `this.getChildOne()` points to, now it points to a new instance. (So you might as well eliminate the assignment `current = this.getChildOne()`: unless `getChildOne` has side effects, this assignment is pointless, because you immediately overwrite it by setting `current` to something else.)

To actually modify some attribute of `this`, you'll want to write something like:

```
if(i == 1)
{
    this.setChildOne(new MyTree());
}
```